# How do I make plots appear in a knitr vignette using dev.new()?

Tags: r, plot, knitr, cran

My package produces a number of graphs, often more than one at once.

Using `x11` or `windows` devices there is no problem, `knitr` builds the vignette with images included.

However a requirement of submission to the CRAN repository is the use of `dev.new` for platform independent plotting. If I replace `x11` or `windows` with `dev.new` then no images appear in my vignette.

Is there a solution to this? At first I thought this was related to plotting in RStudio but use of the new argument `dev.new(noRStudioGD = FALSE)` did not help. Additionally building the package from the command line did not solve the problem.

Cheers,

Tom

(Windows 7 x64)
(R 3.1.1)
(RStudio 0.98.507)

Comment: typically you don't need to open a device yourself, knitr does it for you. The devices you mention are for interactive use, how do you plan the interaction with knitr, which runs in its own non-interactive session?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is, you do not use `dev.new()` at all (or [`dev.off()`](http://yihui.name/en/2012/06/enjoyable-reproducible-research/) or dev.whatever...). If you want a longer answer, please include a minimal reproducible example demonstrating what your problem really is.

Comment: Thanks Yihui and baptiste, you're dead right of course, I didn't need to open a new device at all. Cheers, Tom

Comment: What if I have an analysis function that produces multiple plots? I need to use `dev.new()` in order to have it work interactively. And even if it produces just a single plot, I like my functions to not override previous plots without having to manually do `dev.new()`... is there no way to get such functions to work with `knitr`?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same difficulty. 
Here's one approach that worked:

```
p1 <- function(x, knitr=FALSE){
    plot(x)
    if(!knitr) dev.new()
    plot(x^2)
}
```

The argument `knitr=` is *only* used in vignette building.

Now, in the `.Rnw` file in `/vignettes` put something like:

```
%\VignetteEngine{knitr::knitr}
%\VignetteIndexEntry{p1}
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

<<setup, include=FALSE>>=
library("knitr")
### Set global chunk options
opts_chunk$set(eval=TRUE,
   ## text results
   echo=TRUE,
   results=c('markup', 'asis', 'hold', 'hide')[1],
   ## plots
   fig.path=c('figure', 'figure/minimal-')[1],
   fig.keep=c('high', 'none', 'all', 'first', 'last')[1],
   fig.align=c('center', 'left', 'right', 'default')[1],
   fig.show=c('hold', 'asis', 'animate', 'hide')[1],
   dev=c('pdf', 'png', 'tikz')[1],
   fig.width=7, fig.height=7, #inches
   fig.env=c('figure', 'marginfigure')[1],
   fig.pos=c('', 'h', 't', 'b', 'p', 'H')[1]
   )
@

<<plot1>>
library("myPackage")
x <- seq(10)
p1(x, knitr=TRUE)
@

\end{document}
```